# Fuji X-T4 location download indicator blinking

Tags: fujifilm, camera-controls, geotagging, bluetooth

I'd was using the Fuji Cam Remote app to test image download to iPhone over bluetooth/wifi, and had disconnected, and turned off bluetooth on the camera.

Now, the "location data download status" indicator (a globe with a pin it in, if you look hard enough) is constantly blinking red whilst shooting. It's labelled 52 on page 13 on the manual.

I've power-cycled the camera and, in Setup, Connection, Bluetooth (which is off, though I did try turning it back on briefly), I've changed Smartphone sync setting from *Location and time* to just *Time*, then to *Off*, but it's still flashing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it (rather obvious in hindsight) - Setup, Connection Setting, General Settings, Geotagging > OFF.

Answer (score -2):

The only way is to perform an initialization. It's an obvious bug

Comment: This contradicts the other answer that gives directions on how to solve the problem. What leads you to believe the only way to solve the problem is to perform an initialization?